# How could I apply different font size on different screen?

Tags: gnome, display, fonts, display-resolution

I have two screens with the same resolution 1080p but one is 14-inch and another 23.8-inch, so I would like to apply different font sizes to them (for example, 14-pixel in the small screen and 11-pixel in the bigger one).

But I don't know how to do that because:

1. `gnome-tweaks-tool` can only set the font size for all screens
2. `system setting -> Displays` can set `Scale` separately but both only have two options `100%` and `200%` which are not suitable nor precise.

So how could I apply different font sizes on different screens?

Comment: It's 12/2019 and I have come here directed by google. The command you are looking for is `xrandr --current` to show your monitors. `xrandr --output <device> --scale <X>x<Y>` scale down everything one of your monitors. This is not ideal as your screen will be blurred. I am current searching for scaling font only in on screen.

Comment: have you found a solution to scale down font size only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings there is an option "Fractional scaling" which will allow you other values than 200%.

Note, that it is not ideal as your screen will be blurred. so maybe a better solution is to just set different font DPI for each monitor:

1. Open the System Settings application.
2. Go to the "Displays" section.
3. For each monitor, click the gear icon in the upper-right corner and select "Scale for menu and title bars."

Comment: Thanks! This question was posted on Ubuntu 18.04, so newer Ubuntu versions may have solutions in system setting :-)