# Different scaling with dual monitor setup: slow in x11, blurry in wayland

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, fonts, display-resolution, wayland

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I just got a new 4k monitor which I am now using together with the previous 1080 one.

The 4k display is unreadable at 100% scaling, so at first, I turned on fractional scaling to 150% on the 4k display (leaving the 1080 at 100%). This worked great, except that everything was noticeably slower. Googling suggested that this is a common issue with Xorg and there is nothing that can be done. One solution was to change the font scaling in gnome-tweaks instead of fractional scaling. This worked great, everything was fast and readable on the 4k display, but the font on the second display is too large. One [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083973/how-could-i-apply-different-font-size-on-different-screen) I found was to use `xrandr` to scale down everything on the 1080 display but this results in a very blurry display.
More Googling suggested that I should not be using Xorg, but Wayland, as it is fast and it is the future.
So I tried Wayland, with fractional scaling of the 4k display, and it was indeed very fast. However, the fonts are blurry. Googling again shows that this is a common problem.

So what should I do?
Should I upgrade to 21.10? Will it help?
Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 9):

You need to run your Desktop session under Wayland which has been the default since Ubuntu 22.04

If you still experience blurry fonts It's because the particular application running is not Wayland Native, instead running in "legacy" X11 mode.

Most if not all gnome-shell components should be Wayland native in a later release of Ubuntu. Firefox supports Wayland natively but might need to be started with a particular flag on older releases of Ubuntu/Firefox.

For Firefox it's:

```
  MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox
```

For Spotify it's:

```
 spotify --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

An easy way to see if an application is on Wayland is to install and run the xeyes terminal application (available in x11-apps package).
It starts a pair of eyes that "follow" your mouse cursor.
If The eyes can "follow" the mouse cursor when hoovering in a application it's not running Natively. If the eyes stop moving It is native.

Then either the application isn't configured properly or simply doesn't support Wayland yet.